# Is there a way to run react Application on SpringBoot and to in Kubernetes?

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices

I am running the React Application on Spring Boot which runs as containers in Kubernetes. When the react application interacts with the backend through REST, It should resolve the dns of the REST URI.

I have tried directly giving the service name(i.e. while calling the REST API from react application i have given the https://service-name:port/api/v1/test/), but it is not working.

Comment: please share how to configure connection string? how to define service name, .etc. ... ?

Comment: Service name is the Kubernetes Service name which will be given while creating Kubernetees service.

Comment: 1. Are you using bare-metal or On-Prem (Cloud provider). 2. Please provide output of `kubectl get svc <svc_name> -o yaml`

Comment: Since the React application ultimately runs in the browser, it can't access the Kubernetes-internal host names.  You need to expose your API using a Service or Ingress object, and point the application at that.

Comment: Just to add to what @DavidMaze said - if using a Service then configure it in a way that it is accessible from outside the Kubernetes cluster: [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) or, if applicable for the environment, [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) type.

Answer (score 0):

In case your `backend` is on another `namespace` use the following format:

```
<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc:port
```

For a Kubernetes service `demo-ser` on `demo` namespace the URL will be something like:

```
https://demo-ser.demo.svc:8080/
```

Comment: Both are on the same namespace.

Comment: @chandu, what is the error message? provide the service yaml if possible.

Comment: When i open the react application from Client and Open the developers tool to debug... the application calls rest api( https://service-name:port/api/v1/test/) it shows the ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.